# How to add a single value in datagridview with c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, datagridview

I am trying to perform a database query, which should only bring me a single value, since I do a search by the product id, then when displaying the value in the griddataview it is not displayed, it is only displayed if I get all values from the database.

In this image it brings me all the data:

[image]

but when searching by id so that it only shows me the values of that field, it does not show them.

[image]

This is my code, the function "execute_GetById()" makes the connection to the database and queries with sqlcommand:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        GrdShoes.DataSource = execute_GetAll();
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        GrdShoes.DataSource = execute_GetById(Convert.ToInt32(TxtId.Text));
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you be querying the database again anyway? You are getting all the data when you load the form so anything you get after that will be duplicated because you already have it. Why not just filter the data that you already have?

Comment: As for the specific question? What exactly does `execute_GetById` return? Is it a `DataTable`? Have you debugged the code to see whether that `DataTable` actually contains data?

Comment: Please update the question with the implementations of `execute_GetAll` and `execute_GetById`.

Comment: @John The truth is a project, but I was specified that a query must be made every time an action is performed, such as delete, select, insert, etc. Try to use the debugger, and if it brings me the data, even the value of the GrdShoes are the values of the query.

Comment: @jhmckimm The getAll and getById methods come from a dll developed by the company I work for and as such I cannot see the code, I only know that the properties are used to make the connection and query with sobsqlCommand.

Comment: How about you answer the actual questions I asked? Does `execute_GetById` return a `DataTable` or does it return something else and, if so, what? Have you debugged to determine whether whatever it returns contains the data expected, which would require that you assign it to a variable and examine that variable when the debugger breaks?

Comment: @John I use the Auto and Local windows and I get the data as required, I inspect the method I use and it shows several rows and columns, the first column is the Name, Value and then Type, the rows have a wrench icon followed by the fields of my database and in the "Value" column it shows me the values, it shows me something like this: Name "Nike" , Id 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that it does not return a list, that it is only a value, I only cast the value to type list

```
List<Shoes> shoe = new List<Shoes>();
Shoe data = execute_GetById(Convert.ToInt32(TxtId.Text));
shoe.Add(data);
GrdBarcos.DataSource = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store your database values in datatable or list in just one load then start querying using LINQ. I used DataTable here.

```
DataTable ToView = DT.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(w => Convert.ToInt32(w.ItemArray[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text))
                            .ToList()
                            .CopyToDataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ToView;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: DT is your DataTable with database values.

Comment: I'm a noob at this,  but for me it returns a values ​​object, not a dataTable

Comment: (You mean from database?) Yes, it is object if you retrieve a data from database, just use datatable.Load(reader); you will get the actual table in your database.